# Image Carrousel - jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an image carousel that changes with 4 images, and I would like it to rotate one image at a time, for example, that the first 4 images appear, but as the rest of the images appear as they change.

In my jQuery code that I appended in the code I have not been able to do it.

If someone could help me I would appreciate it, I have tried several ways but I have not succeeded.

He then sent the images of how the image carousel is currently working.

When loading the first 4 images:
[image]

But when it loads the other images, if I don't have 4 more images, as is the case, it leaves the carousel empty on the right side and it looks bad:

[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://henao.hoztcrea.com/laboral/wp-content/themes/jarida/js/jquery.cycle.all.js' id='tie-cycle-js'></script>
<section class="cat-box scroll-box scroll-box-wide tie-cat-7">
   <h2 class="cat-box-title"><a href="posts\category\world\index.htm">Scrolling Box</a></h2>
   <div class="cat-box-content">
      <div class="group_items-box" id="wslideshow7">
         <div class="scroll-item">
            <div class="post-thumbnail">
               <a href="posts\48\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post With Featured Image" rel="bookmark">
               <img width="300" height="160" src="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\7413497016_9434c1917a_b-300x160.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="Test 2" loading="lazy" srcset="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\7413497016_9434c1917a_b-300x160.jpg 300w, wp-content\uploads\2012\07\7413497016_9434c1917a_b-620x330.jpg 620w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> </a>
            </div>
            <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="posts\48\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post With Featured Image" rel="bookmark">Post With Featured Image</a></h3>
            <p class="post-meta">
               <span class="tie-date">July 30, 2012</span> 
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="scroll-item">
            <div class="post-thumbnail">
               <a href="posts\33\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post with SoundCloud" rel="bookmark">
               <img width="300" height="160" src="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\4088743235_690996beef_o-300x160.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\4088743235_690996beef_o-300x160.jpg 300w, wp-content\uploads\2012\07\4088743235_690996beef_o-620x330.jpg 620w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> </a>
            </div>
            <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="posts\33\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post with SoundCloud" rel="bookmark">Post with SoundCloud</a></h3>
            <p class="post-meta">
               <span class="tie-date">July 30, 2012</span> 
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="scroll-item">
            <div class="post-thumbnail">
               <a href="posts\30\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post with Image + Lightbox" rel="bookmark">
               <img width="300" height="160" src="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\4756831209_cfe3227937_b-300x160.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\4756831209_cfe3227937_b-300x160.jpg 300w, wp-content\uploads\2012\07\4756831209_cfe3227937_b-620x330.jpg 620w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> </a>
            </div>
            <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="posts\30\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post with Image + Lightbox" rel="bookmark">Post with Image + Lightbox</a></h3>
            <p class="post-meta">
               <span class="tie-date">July 30, 2012</span> 
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="scroll-item">
            <div class="post-thumbnail">
               <a href="posts\24\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post With Video" rel="bookmark">
               <img width="300" height="160" src="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\5709944739_578bc434a7_b-300x160.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\5709944739_578bc434a7_b-300x160.jpg 300w, wp-content\uploads\2012\07\5709944739_578bc434a7_b-620x330.jpg 620w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> </a>
            </div>
            <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="posts\24\index.htm" title="Permalink to Post With Video" rel="bookmark">Post With Video</a></h3>
            <p class="post-meta">
               <span class="tie-date">July 30, 2012</span> 
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="scroll-item">
            <div class="post-thumbnail">
               <a href="posts\14\index.htm" title="Permalink to Maecenas mattis, tortor ut posuere aliquam" rel="bookmark">
               <img width="300" height="160" src="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\7543602860_c741e700c0_b-300x160.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="wp-content\uploads\2012\07\7543602860_c741e700c0_b-300x160.jpg 300w, wp-content\uploads\2012\07\7543602860_c741e700c0_b-620x330.jpg 620w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> </a>
            </div>
            <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="posts\14\index.htm" title="Permalink to Maecenas mattis, tortor ut posuere aliquam" rel="bookmark">Maecenas mattis, tortor ut posuere aliquam</a></h3>
            <p class="post-meta">
               <span class="tie-date">July 28, 2012</span> 
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="scroll-item">
            <div class="post-thumbnail">
               <a href="posts\39\index.htm" title="Permalink to Elementum mauris aliquam ut" rel="bookmark">
               <img width="300" height="160" src="wp-content\uploads\2011\07\4148265552_7b438be4ab_b-300x160.jpg" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="wp-content\uploads\2011\07\4148265552_7b438be4ab_b-300x160.jpg 300w, wp-content\uploads\2011\07\4148265552_7b438be4ab_b-620x330.jpg 620w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"> <span title="Not bad !" class="stars-large"><span style="width:72%"></span></span>
               </a>
            </div>
            <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="posts\39\index.htm" title="Permalink to Elementum mauris aliquam ut" rel="bookmark">Elementum mauris aliquam ut</a></h3>
            <p class="post-meta">
               <span class="tie-date">July 30, 2011</span> 
            </p>
         </div>
        
         
         <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-nav"><a id="nextw7" href="#"><i class="tieicon-right-open"></i></a><a class="prev-scroll" id="prevw7" href="#"><i class="tieicon-left-open"></i></a></div>
   </div>
</section>
<!--<div class="clear"></div>-->
<!-- slider1 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var vids = jQuery("#wslideshow7 .scroll-item");
    for(var i = 0; i < vids.length; i+=4) {
      vids.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll('<div class="group_items"></div>');
    }
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#wslideshow7').cycle({
            fx:     'scrollHorz',
            timeout: 3000,
            //pager:  '#nav7',
            slideExpr: '.group_items',
            prev:   '#prevw7',
            next:   '#nextw7',
            speed: 300,
            pause: true
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm going to assume this is the documentation for jQuery cycle https://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

Comment: Or are you using cycle2? https://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

Comment: pls edit to a working snippet, `jQuery` no added to snippet,  `jQuery cycle` also not added

Comment: ok, added jquery.cycle.all.js, I ask you if you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative method if you are open to changing your jquery carousel cycle plugin.

A more simple and elegant jquery carousel solution is to use [ken wheeler's slick carousel](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

Slick carousel automatically handles your problem straight out the box (as should all carousel plugins)

See working example below using your provided source code...

*(i've added basic custom css to match your design as you didn't provide css)*

```js
$('#wslideshow7').slick({
  infinite: false,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="your-prev-button-class"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></button>',
  nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="your-next-button-class"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>'
});
```

```css
.scroll-box {
  margin: 10px;
  border-top: 6px solid #cb242a;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.cat-box-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #cb242a;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0px 10px 3px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.cat-box-title A {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.cat-box-content {
  position: relative;
}

#wslideshow7 {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#wslideshow7 .slick-list {
  margin: 0 -6px;
}

#wslideshow7 .slick-arrow {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #cb242a;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  padding: 6px 0 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#wslideshow7 .slick-arrow.slick-disabled I {
  opacity: .5;
}

#wslideshow7 .your-prev-button-class {
  right: 36px;
}

#wslideshow7 .your-next-button-class {
  right: 0;
}

.scroll-item {
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.scroll-item .post-thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.scroll-item .post-thumbnail > A {
  display: block;
}

.scroll-item .post-thumbnail > A > IMG {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.scroll-item .post-box-title {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.scroll-item .post-box-title A {
  color: #444444;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.scroll-item .post-meta {
  font-size: .75rem;
  color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<section class="cat-box scroll-box scroll-box-wide tie-cat-7">
  <h2 class="cat-box-title"><a href="#">Scrolling Box</a></h2>
  <div class="cat-box-content">
    <div class="group_items-box" id="wslideshow7">
      <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
          <a href="#" title="Permalink to Post With Featured Image" rel="bookmark">
            <img width="300" height="160" src="https://placehold.co/300x160" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="Test 2" loading="lazy"> 
          </a>
        </div>
        <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="#" title="Permalink to Post With Featured Image" rel="bookmark">Post With Featured Image</a></h3>
        <p class="post-meta">
          <span class="tie-date">July 30, 2012</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
          <a href="#" title="Permalink to Post with SoundCloud" rel="bookmark">
            <img width="300" height="160" src="https://placehold.co/300x160" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy">
          </a>
        </div>
        <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="#" title="Permalink to Post with SoundCloud" rel="bookmark">Post with SoundCloud</a></h3>
        <p class="post-meta">
          <span class="tie-date">July 30, 2012</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
          <a href="#" title="Permalink to Post with Image + Lightbox" rel="bookmark">
            <img width="300" height="160" src="https://placehold.co/300x160" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy"> </a>
        </div>
        <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="#" title="Permalink to Post with Image + Lightbox" rel="bookmark">Post with Image + Lightbox</a></h3>
        <p class="post-meta">
          <span class="tie-date">July 30, 2012</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
          <a href="#" title="Permalink to Post With Video" rel="bookmark">
            <img width="300" height="160" src="https://placehold.co/300x160" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="#" title="Permalink to Post With Video" rel="bookmark">Post With Video</a></h3>
        <p class="post-meta">
          <span class="tie-date">July 30, 2012</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
          <a href="#" title="Permalink to Maecenas mattis, tortor ut posuere aliquam" rel="bookmark">
            <img width="300" height="160" src="https://placehold.co/300x160" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="#" title="Permalink to Maecenas mattis, tortor ut posuere aliquam" rel="bookmark">Maecenas mattis, tortor ut posuere aliquam</a></h3>
        <p class="post-meta">
          <span class="tie-date">July 28, 2012</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
          <a href="#" title="Permalink to Elementum mauris aliquam ut" rel="bookmark">
            <img width="300" height="160" src="https://placehold.co/300x160" class="attachment-tie-large size-tie-large wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy">
          </a>
        </div>
        <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="#" title="Permalink to Elementum mauris aliquam ut" rel="bookmark">Elementum mauris aliquam ut</a></h3>
        <p class="post-meta">
          <span class="tie-date">July 30, 2011</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here is a jsFiddle version too...

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/t2qxdok7/1/

There are some key upsides to using slick carousel...

- Infinite scrolling `true` by default (set to `false` in my example above)
- Responsive updating
- Responsive slide count to display on defined breakpoints ([see *Responsive Display* in docs](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/))
- Touch drag to scroll
- *...and loads more cool options*

Hope this helps!